# Differences-in-Differences without Control-Group

Tags: panel-data, difference-in-difference, causalimpact

As part of my master's thesis, I am currently investigating the impact of a law in the area of tax law on municipalities. Usually, according to the literature I found, the **differences-in-differences** approach is used in such cases. I have data from about 70 municipalities over an eight-year period.

Now in my case I don't have anything to use as a control group, since the law basically applies to every municipality. Can I **modify** the DiD **method** to use a municipality as a control group to which the law applies in principle, but which does not apply in practice due to other characteristics? Do you have other ideas how I can proceed here? Is a ****regression discontinuity** design** a possible alternative approach?

Comment: You might want to look into Google's CausalImpact library. Out of the box, it might not have what you're looking for; however, it might offer inspiration.

Comment: DiD assumes two groups and two time periods. What would have happened to the treatment group if it did not receive treatment exposure (counterfactual)? With parallel trends assumption, we believe that treatment group counterfactual would have changed at same rate as control group.

Comment: Synthetic control, on the other hand, generates a synthetic control as a weighted average of candidate control randomization units. CausalImpact uses Bayesian Structural Time Series (BSTS) to not make a single blanket synthetic control but to evaluate best weighted average of candidate control randomization units over time.

Comment: If you really don't have a control but you do have data pre-treatment exposure, then you might be able to forecast the counterfactual using BSTS. Then for each randomization unit, compute the lift between forecasted counterfactual and observed (with treatment exposure.)

Comment: FYI- I'm not aware of anyone using this design yet. So you might be innovating in this space but conversely, you might ruffle some feathers.

Comment: I have not heard of the causalimpact package yet. 
Thank you, I will have a look at it.